# Should user be prompted when starting a bounty and clicking away from popup?

Tags: feature-request, bug, bounty, popup

I started a bounty and was on step 3, wrote up a nice little description of my bounty, and then I accidentally clicked on the background of the site which caused the DHTML popup to go away without prompting me. It wasn't a ton of text, but I lost what I wrote and ended up just deciding not to write anything the second time around.

Suggestion: add a prompt asking the user if they want to cancel or only close the dialog if a close/cancel button is explicitly clicked.

Comment: Other solution is to just disable close on clicking the background. The dialogs have a close button, that's enough.

Comment: yeah, this is super-annoying. Ditto for the flag dialog, close as duplicate, and a few moderator tools.

Comment: Just lost another optional description I wrote on step 3... twice... Fortunately I have learned from past experience and this time I had some partial "backups" in my copy buffer ([Klipper](https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper)). I've had some bad feedback on the bounty descriptions in the past, so I usually try to polish these for a rather long before submitting. I'll probably use a separate text editor next time.